# How to remove my printer from shared list?

Tags: networking, samba, sharing

I have two printers in my system called "HP-LaserJet-1200" and "hp1320". If I right-click on their icons under "Printers" windows, the `Shared` item is not selected and I can select it. But both printers are listed under `smbclient -L localhost` command and are listed if I connect to my laptop from another machine on the LAN network.

Are my printers shares?
If yes, how to remove their shares?
And If no, why they are listed in `smbclient -L localhost` output?